# Should I rewrite the loop header for iterating the STL vector?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Which is better?

```
 for (auto anItem = aVector.begin(), endVector = aVector.end(); anItem != endVector ; ++anItem )
```

or

```
for (auto anItem = aVector.begin(), anItem != aVector.end(); ++anItem )
```

Comment: The one that actually compiles? (Also, have you considered `for(auto&& anItemNotAnIteratorLikeInYourExamples : aVector)`?)

Comment: They are not necessarily the same, depending on loop body.

Comment: @PiotrNycz I'm not sure.  A number of operations which would cause the first to fail will also invalidate iterators into the vector.

Comment: @JamesKanze Safer does not mean 100% safe :D Re-sizing to smaller size and erasing element(s) usually do not invalidate vector iterators - but first loop will try to iterate over current end().,,

Comment: The second one isn't safe in that regard either.

Comment: @jrok It is not safe per C++ standard - but in practice I never seen std::vector implementation which will reallocate on shrinking...

Comment: @PiotrNycz: They aren't allowed to reallocate until capacity is too small for a new size. (Iterator validity is a whole different thing, though.)

Comment: @GManNickG If I understood you correctly, they would never reallocated when becoming smaller. When I wrote about Iterators safety in these loops I only meant operations on iterators `++it, it1!=it2` not on values under them `it->,*it`

Comment: @PiotrNycz The standard requires iterators into `std::vector` to remain valid except when 1) there is an insertion or a deletion in front of or at the iterator or 2) the results of an insertion would otherwise cause `size()` to exceed `capacity()`.  An implementation is never allowed to reduce `capacity()` except when explicitly requested.

Comment: @JamesKanze thanks. It is nice to know. Actually I always think in this way about std::vector iterators - but now I know this is correct approach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use second - the simpler one.

I believe you expect that first could be faster, but typical implementation of std::vector::end() is to return simple pointer pointing to first element after the last one in vector, so effectively there is not performance improvement in second case because end() is always inline function. Maybe it could be performance improvement when you store current end() in `const iterator` like this:

```
const decltype(aVector.end()) endVector = aVector.end();
for (auto anItem = aVector.begin(); anItem != endVector ; ++anItem )
```

But this loop and your first loop is less safe in many cases than your second loop. That is why I see almost always second loop.

[UPDATE]

I do not believe that first loop has any advantage over the second when talking about performance. Modern compilers can detect that aVector.end() result is not changing through entire loop so they are free to optimize. The only performance advantage of first loop could be case when aVector changes in loop - but this results in wrong behavior.

So, from whatever side to look at this question - the second loop is always better.

[UPDATE2]

Just to check it. I wrote two functions like this:

```
int test1(std::vector<int>& a)
{
    int retVal = 0;

    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin(), aend = a.end(); it != aend; ++it)
    {
        retVal += *it;
    }
    return retVal;
}

int test2(std::vector<int>& a)
{
    int retVal = 0;
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
    {
        retVal += *it;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

And compiled them to assembler `g++ -O3 -S`. There is no difference in assembler code on my computer/compiler - however this does not mean they wouldn't be any differences in all cases.

Comment: I actually measured this (some time back), and the first form (in the original posting) is measurably faster.  For loops that do almost nothing; in most cases, I agree that the difference will be negligible, and that you should use the form specified by the coding guidelines (which in turn should be based on readability, which is in the eye of the beholder).

Comment: @JamesKanze Just to be sure: you tested with full optimization (like g++ -O3) for loops which did not alter vector size? I believed that for full optimization and for loops which did not alter vector size the performance shall not change - but I did not measured...

Comment: My tests were with `-O3` as well.  They are fairly old, and the compiler might have gotten better, but there was a measurable difference.  (Not that I'd change my style because of it.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I just run a minute ago a test with some very old compiler (g++ 4.1.1) on some server computer (sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-480R) - with `g++ -O3 -S` to produce assembler output for two functions summing all `vector<int>` elements using both approaches. There is no difference in assembler code between these styles.

Answer (score 1):

The second is better, and that's because **all** (yes, 100%) programmers use it. (assuming you're not erasing anything wile iterating, in which case a `for` loop wouldn't be the best choice)

Comment: That's what I felt until recently.  Where I currently work, however, the first form is more common, and is required by the coding guidelines.  (The first form is preferable if you need to access `end` within the loop as well.  Not usually the case, but it can occur.)